# How to place folder with terraform files in a docker container and further deploy it to azure

Tags: azure, directory, terraform, docker-container, infrastructure-as-code

I have my infrastructure as a code folder with distinct terraform files stored on Azure in a storage account on a resource group that is only used for storing state or secrets used for automation.
How can I place the folder in a docker container and further use it so that secrets remain private?

Answer (score 1):

Never put secrets in a docker image. They are easily reversible and aren't treated as secret.

You would normally store your Terraform files (without secrets) in a source repository that has a pipeline attached. The pipeline could have the secrets defined as "secret variables" (different pipeline tools have different terms for the same thing).

For example, say you need to provide a particular API key to talk to a service with Terraform. Often the provider supports an environment variable out for the credential by default (check their docs), in cases where it doesn't you can create a Terraform variable to do so and set the secret on the pipeline as mentioned earlier.

e.g.

In terraform:

```
variable "key" {
  type = "string"
  sensitive = true
}

provider "someprovider" {
  project = "..."
  region  = "..."
  key     = var.key
}
```

Then in the pipeline you would define something like:

```
TF_VAR_key=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Normally within the pipeline tools you can provide variables to the various steps or docker images (such as Terraform image).